# Using Numpy.where() with a function on each element

Tags: numpy

I have a rather complicated function, say:

```
def func(elem):
    // blah blah blah
    return True
    // blah blah blah
    return False
```

I wish to use the numpy.where() function along the lines of

```
arr2 = np.where(func(arr1), arr1, 0)
```

But when I try this syntax and debug, I see that in `func`, that the entire array is passed rather than individual elements. The typical use cases I see in the documentation/examples only rely on simple comparators like `arr < 5`, but I need something quite a bit fancier that I don't want to try and write in a single line.

If this is possible, or if there is some vectorized substitute (emphasis on efficiency), any insights appreciated.

Comment: The entire array is passed, because you supply the entire array as an input argument. One solution is for your function to go over the input array and return another array of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it by using `np.vectorize`, followed by a `list comprehension`, not `np.where`. Maybe from this, one can find out a way to use numpy rather than of a list comprehension.

```py
func_vec = np.vectorize(func)
[arr1 if cond else 0 for cond in func_vec(arr1)]
```

Anyways, by using `func_vec(arr1)` you get the True/False values per element.

---

Note: If you want a new array like `arr1`, replacing by 0 the elements that return False in your function, then this should work:

```
arr2 = np.where(func_vec(arr1), arr1, 0)
```

---

**Edit:**

Indeed, `np.vectorize` **is not** optimized to performance (by bad), is essentially a [for loop under the hood](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize). So I would recommend trying to write your function in a vectorized way rather than trying to vectorize it thereafter.

For example, try converting a function like this:

```py
def func(elem):
    if elem > 5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

to something like this:

```py
def func(elem):
    return elem > 5
```

so that you can easily apply `func(arr1)` without error.

If you really have a function that returns just `True` or `False`, I'm pretty sure you can do it, regardless of its complexity. Anyways we're here to help you out!

Comment: Although now that I try this it seems it is just as slow as simply iterating through the array and applying func. I wonder if there are other methods/resources to apply a function efficiently to each element of an array.

Comment: Hey, which one of the code chunk worked for you? The first one with `list comprehension` or the last one with `np.where`? Just to know your goal...

Comment: The np.vectorize followed by a list comprehension. Well it all "worked", it's just a question of speed.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I think the best way you to solve your problem is by working directly within your function. Let me know if it works. If no, maybe it's better to remove this answer as accepted so that someone else may come with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you try to get the elements of `arr1` you want using `func` function, but judging from the definition `func` works for a single element. You need a True/False array of the same shape as `arr1` to do so.

If I get it right, a potential solution would be to modify `func` to operate on the whole array and not only on one element and return the True/False array of shape `arr1.shape` you need for `np.where`, since you want to do it in a single line that way.